# I am trying to copy a table from one word file (.docx) to another using python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

while I am trying to copy tables from one word document to another, I am able to copy the table content but not the actual styling and formatting in the original table.

```
table1(output_doc,table._tbl)

def table1(output_doc_name,element):
    output_para = output_doc_name.add_paragraph(text="")
    output_para._p.addnext(element)
```

with this function I was able to copy the content but not the styling associated to the old table. and also my Header for the table is gone.

[image: copied table]

this is the copied table in my new word document

[image: original table]

this is the original and I want this to be replicated.

please help.